# Storing large data in a string and assigning it to a text view?

Tags: java, android, string, arraylist, textview

I am basically trying to make a Bible reader app. I have a sqlite DB of the Bible. My intention is to select all the verse from the Db and assign it to a `TextView` which is in a `ViewPager`. Below is my select Query.

```
String SelectQuery = "SELECT verse FROM Bible";
Cursor c = helper.executeQuery(SelectQuery);
int cu = c.getCount();
if (c.getCount() > 0 && c.moveToFirst() && c != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
        String Verse = c.getString(0);
        c.moveToNext();
        chapterList.add(Verse);//This is an arraylist
    }
}

String s = removeCharacter(chapterList.toString());
versetxt.setText(s);//This is the textview
```

The app is crashing because of outOfMemory. So I can get that I have created a mess. Could anyone please tell me the correct way to do this?

NOTE: I know there are lot of questions about saving a large string. I could not find a solution from that. Hence I am posting this question. So before marking this question as a duplicate, please answer this.

Will appreciate any help.

Comment: I would suggest to load a single verse at a time in textview

Comment: @VivekMishra Thanks. But can you post a small code for that

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding complete string at a time.You already have a arraylist use it. In a for loop like this

```
for(int i=0;i<chapterList.size();i++)
{
versetxt.setText(chapterList.get(i));
}
```

Some thing like this you should do

Comment: That will set just the last chapter

Comment: keep setting it in view pager too and detect swipe to change text

Comment: What do you mean? You've looped over the whole list of strings, setting the textview each time. When the loop exits, only the very last string will be displayed

Comment: @cricket_007 Yeah. Only the last is displayed.

Comment: So this doesn't answer the question because OP wants to display all verses in all chapters

Comment: @cricket_007 .So do you have an answer?

Comment: To avoid an out of memory on a textview for a really long string? Not really

Comment: I can't even delete this answer